# Prevent empty image source error from W3C validator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several logs with photo's. In the index.html appears a small version of each photo.
Originally each photo was link to the full size picture, but then one needs the browsers back button to return to the index.
Now I made it a link show.html, passing the name of the photo as a parameter:

```
https://gdraisma....nl/js/show.html?foto=DSC08169.JPG&leg=DD%202023:07:02%20om%2012:27:28
```

In show.html in the tag the src is empty, as it is filled by javascript, from the url parameter foto.

However the W3C Markup validator complains:

```
    Error: Bad value for attribute src on element img: Must be non-empty.

    From line 30, column 2; to line 30, column 53

    imgbox">↩   <img id='thisFoto' class="center-fit" src="" alt="">↩   <p i
```

The page functions as expected, but I would like to keep W3C satisfied. What is the best way to do that?
Gerrit

This the show.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> 
    Foto
    </title>
   <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    p {
        text-align: center
    }
        .imgbox {
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .center-fit {
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 95vh;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="index.html">
    <div class="imgbox">
    <img id='thisFoto' class="center-fit" src="" alt="">
    <p id="legenda"></p>
    </div></a>
    <script>
    foto= new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("foto")
    leg= new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("leg")
        document.getElementById("thisFoto").src="img/" + foto;
        document.getElementById("legenda").innerHTML=leg;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just give it a default value, e.g. `src='#'`. You're going to replace it anyway. Don't forget to assign a value to the alt attribute too, though.

Comment: Thanks!, Alohci. The W3.org validator has no further complaints